# How to prove that $E=2 \text{ GeV}$ drives to maximum of neutrino oscillation for $L=811 \text{ km}$ of NOvA experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

How to prove that E=2 GeV drives to maximum of neutrino oscillation for L=811 km of NOvA experiment (as NOvA claims) ?

The dependence for $\nu_\mu\rightarrow\nu_\mu$ is $\sin^2{\frac{\Delta m^2_{32}L}{4E}}$

So we try to check if $E=\frac{\Delta m^2_{32}L}{4\pi/2}$

From $1=\hbar c$ for physicists of this thematic, and $\hbar c=197MeV.fm$, I get : L=811 km <=> $811000/(0.197\times 10^{-15})\ GeV^{-1}$
so L<=>$4.117\times 10^{21}\ GeV^{-1}$

According to wikipedia, we have $\Delta m^2_{32}=2.44\times 10^{-3}\ eV^2=2.44\times 10^{-3}\times 10^{-18}\ GeV^2=2.44\times 10^{-21}\ GeV^2$

So we get :
$E=2.44\times 10^{-21}\ GeV^2\times 4.117\times 10^{21}\ GeV^{-1} / 12.56$

So : $E=0.8\ GeV$, different to 2 GeV

I'm sure than 2 GeV is true, so where is my mistake ?

Maybe the keypoint is that there is matter effect in NOvA experiment, so thatt previous formula is too naive. If this is the point, I would need confirmation from experts.

Comment: For typesetting units, set them off with a short space and set the units upright `0.8 \,\mathrm{GeV}` ($0.8\,\mathrm{GeV}$) and when combining use either a short space `\mathrm{MeV\,fm}` ($\mathrm{MeV\,fm}$) or a centered dot `\mathrm{MeV\cdot fm}` ($\mathrm{MeV\cdot fm}$). Thus endeth the the first pet peeve.

Comment: Next $1 = \hbar c = 197\,\mathrm{MeV\cdot fm}$ isn't right. Both $1 = \hbar c$ and $\hbar c = 197\,\mathrm{MeV\cdot fm}$ can be right (when you are using natural units and dimensional units), but equality is tansitive so you wrote $1 = 197\,\mathrm{MeV\cdot fm}$ with is false in *every set of units*. Nor is there any motivation to use natural units here. Thus endeth the second pet peeve.

Comment: @dmckee thank you. I have made the fix. here I introduce the natural units because in the formula, there is natural units, else it would not be homogeneous. (since natural units are used in this official formula)

Comment: You've also got a repeated typo on $\Delta m^2$.

Comment: I have to say that I think you *need* a mentor. You seem to be trying to understand the state of the experimental art by reading disertations and papers. Niether of those sources is intended to be an educational resource and they both generally assume that you already have some rough familarity with the customs of the sub-field. People who lived throught the development learn that along the way and people in the usual educational track get it from their advisors and peers. But reading current papers without either kind of preparation is diving into the deep end without your water-wings on.

Comment: @dmckee you have a good point about units : I need to check. Is there a way to put the question "on hold" so that I move back to it after having checked. I do have mentors in particle physics, but not in specific neutrino physics (they don't know anything on neutrino, because each thematic is very specialized)

Comment: to be more clear : I am not working on neutrino physics : but I try to learn some details. As you see from my questions : I am asking myself some not easy questions (for the easy questions, I already know the answers)

Comment: My formula is correct, in natural units. Proof : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation There is an additional formula in Standard Units. I believe that the solution is the matter effect, because my formula is valid in *vacuum*

Comment: @dmckee I have found the solution to my problem. The key point was that I should not use "pi" but "pi/2" : then everything works. Matter effects are typically 20 %, so this was not the explanation. The point was to use pi/2 instead of pi. The reason was that I was using disappareance formula instead of appareance formulas. Kind regards